# how to select last rows where one certain value exist but not if it's in between

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this table. With case#, Linenumber and code#.

```
case#   Linenumber  Code#
99L1HV  1           1510
99L1HV  2           4320
99PX58  1           1510
99PX58  2           4320
99PX58  3           4500
99PX59  1           1510
99PX59  2           918
99PX59  3           4320
```

How can I get the records with the last LineNumber per case# where code = 4320

The output should be like this

```
case#   Linenumber  Code
99L1HV  2           4320
99PX59  3           4320
```

Comment: `SELECT TOP 2 ... FROM .. WHERE code = 4320 ORDER BY LineNumber DESC`

Comment: why `99L1HV` and not `99PX58` ?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear.

Comment: I only want those rows where 4320 is the last registered linenumber. That's why I only want (in this example) 99L1HV  and 99PX59

Answer (score 1):

Using ROW_NUMBER to get a number that's in the opposite order of the linenumber per case#.
Then the last lines will have RN = 1

```
SELECT [case#], Linenumber, [Code#]
FROM
(
    SELECT [case#], Linenumber, [Code#],
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [case#] ORDER BY Linenumber DESC) AS RN
    FROM yourtable
) q
WHERE RN = 1 
  AND [Code#] = 4320
ORDER BY [case#];
```

Or the more concise version.
Using a TOP 1 WITH TIES in combination with an ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES [case#], Linenumber, [Code#]
    FROM yourtable
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [case#] ORDER BY Linenumber DESC)
) q
WHERE [Code#] = 4320
ORDER BY [case#];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as 
(select case#, max(linenumber)
from source_table 
group by case#)
select t1.*
from source_table t1 inner join cte t2
on t1.case# = t2.case# and t1.linenumber = t2.linenumber
where t1.Code# = 4320
```

Comment: That `max(linenumber)` probably needs an alias for this to work.  And to get the expected result a `select t1.*` wouldn't return all the t2 fields.

Answer (score 0):

cte is to generate a running number by case#. rn = 1 will be the last row for each case#

```
; with cte as
(
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by [case#] order by linenumber desc)
    from   yourtable
)
select *
from   cte
where  rn     = 1 
and   [code#] = 4320
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (
    CaseNumber varchar(10),
    LineNumber int,
    CodeNumber int
);

-- Filling the table with data, skipped

select t.*
from @t t
where t.CodeNumber = 4320
    and not exists (
        select 0 from @t x
        where x.CaseNumber = t.CaseNumber
            and x.LineNumber > t.LineNumber
    );
```